# How to use AF laser sensor after installing a custom ROM on LG G5?

Tags: custom-roms, camera, lg-g5

I have LG G5 running on Android 8. I want to install a custom ROM based on Android 11 on it, but I am scared that after the upgrade, I might lose the default camera app because G5 has an AF laser sensor that Google Camera does not support.

If I make an APK of the default camera app and install it again after the upgrade, is it going to work? Or is there any other way to support the AF laser?

Comment: Usually manufacturer specific camera apps that contain special features rely on a proprietary API provided by the phone. Thus extracting the APK will be of no help unless the custom ROM also provides this proprietary API.